# Individually checking constraints for convexity in Optimisation problem valid?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have a quadratic minimisation problem where both the objective fn and constraints have some quadratic terms. (Such as a throttle variable (continous) * On/Off (integer variable)).

My question is: can I check my problem piecewise for convexivity?

So if I analyse each on of my constraints independently and find that they're all linear/convex then the sum of them interacting will also be convex?

I'm trying to figure out if I should be approaching this problem with LP-based techniques (i.e. Gurobi etc.) which I understand is best done on Convex problems, or Evolutionary based techniques (i.e. PSO, GA etc.) if it isn't convex.

Edit/Clarification: I'm aware that including integer terms means it's non-smooth which results in non-convexity (Or at least - I think that's correct). However LP solvers relax the Integer constraints into continuous ones so I don't think it affects the solution quality as much as it getting trapped in a local minima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have constraints where you turn on/off things by multiplying continuous variables with binary variables, you are typically not going to end up with convex (as in convex relaxations etc) models.

Instead, you should model this using big-M strategies. For instance, if you want to model $xy\geq 1$ where $x$ is continuous and $y$ is binary, you introduce a new variable $w$ which represents the product, and you can see the product as a logic condition (if $y=0$ then $w=0$ else $w=x$. This can be written using the big-M constraint $-M(1-y) \leq x-w \leq M(1-y), -My\leq x\leq My$. $M$ is a constant large enough to not restrict $x$ when $y$ is $1$ (for instance, an upper bound on $x$ in any solution). The smaller $M$ you can derive, the better from a numerical point of view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm pretty sure that the Gurobi solver already implements this 'under the hood' hence my edit/clarification in the question. 

My problem has multiple constraint types (it's a real world problem so different phenomenon result in different constraints). I'm really wanting to know if I can analyse each of these constraints separately and come to the conclusion that the problem as a whole is still convex (or not).

Comment: Not sure gurobi does this under the hood automatically. Your question is still vague though. You say LP is best done on convex problems. That statement makes no sense. LP is a very special case of a convex program. You also seem to think that non-smoothness implies non-convexity. That is not the case either. However, as your model can be written as a MILP, that is most certainly the way to solve the problem.

Comment: ...and yes, if every single constraint is convex, then the whole model is convex (as the feasible set then is an intersection of convex sets, which is convex). However, your (relaxed) constraints will not be convex (as they are bilinear products)

Comment: Ah sorry. When I said LP solver I was just referring to sovlers that use the Simplex algorithm at their heart. My problem is MIQP to be specific. With quadratic terms in both the objective and the constraints. 

When you say bilinear products do you just mean quadratic terms? Does the big M formulation avoid this? 

Do you have any suggestions of books/textbooks by anychance? 

Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: No, I mean bilinear, because that is the problem you describe (continuous*binary, thus clearly bilinear). Yes, the big-M reformulation I proposed obviously avoids the bilinearity, that is the whole purpose of the reformulation.

Comment: is there any reason that I couldn't formulate the problem as: obj = Cost*X_throttle. Subject to: 1  >= X_throttle >= X_OnOff*0.7? Thus X_Throttle will be 0 if it's not on, but will be between 0.7 and 1 if it is? Obviously assuming X_OnOff is binary.